# Connecting an SSRS report's data source to a .net web api using basic authentication

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to set up the ability to use my Web API as a data source for creating SSRS Reports. I can successfully access the the data source by using XML and putting in the URL for the call if there is no authentication on the web API. However, when there is basic authentication set, the data source fails with a 401. I tried to add credentials, but it says it only works with Windows integrated security. Can anyone tell me how I can pass basic authentication to the web API through an SSRS data source?